# Prepare commit message hook in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, githooks, pre-commit-hook, hgrc

What is Mercurial's equivalent to the `prepare-commit-message` hook in Git?

Basically what I'm looking for is any hook that runs as part of a commit but before the commit message has been edited by the user. The hook will edit the commit message and the generated message will be shown to the user so it can be validated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial Hook - change a commit message pre commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377011/mercurial-hook-change-a-commit-message-pre-commit)

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, there's no equivalent in Mercurial. There are a few other ways to do this:

- if you use vim, you can *fake* a template [here's the tip](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Fake_A_Commit_Message_Template_In_VIM)
- using a patch to `hgeditor` or using scripts around it ([more here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitMessageTemplate))
- if you use the [Qct extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QctExtension), it supports the use of a file called `commit.template` to seed your commit message

I have not tried any of these, so I cannot offer anything more than pointers. My experience with writing hooks has usually been to validate changesets about to be committed or to validate incoming changesets for master repositories.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the real answer is that there's no good way to do it. I tried your workarounds but none of them fit our workflow I'm afraid.

Comment: Have a look at my above 'possible duplicate' comment, there are some solutions there.